# Why does Kafka need more Heap Space on start-up than when running?

Tags: apache-kafka

We had several instances where Kafka was running just fine, but after a restart would crash with an out-of-memory error. We increased the heap space, but the same would happen again a few days later. So we increased the heap space to 2 GB, then to 4 and finally to 6 GB - since then, everything is running smoothly.

The [Confluent documentation states](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/deployment.html) that "Kafka uses heap space very carefully and does not require setting heap sizes more than 6 GB". Our test servers, where these problems came up, have just a single Kafka instance and a few topics with some GB of data between them. What could be the reason that our Kafka instance (running alongside Zookeeper) needs so much heap space when starting up?

**Edit:** To find out when the OOM error happens during start-up, I reproduced the issue by reducing the heap size to 2G (-Xmx and -Xms JVM parameters) and compared the logs to a working container with more heap space. On start-up, Kafka first recovers unflushed segments, loads producer states/snapshots and writes new producer snapshots. The out-of-memory error happens in this phase:

```
[2024-01-31 08:32:45,309] INFO [LogLoader partition=some-topic-0, dir=/var/lib/kafka/data] Recovering unflushed segment 69396839. 0/1 recovered for some-topic-0. (kafka.log.LogLoader)
[2024-01-31 08:32:45,310] INFO [LogLoader partition=some-topic-0, dir=/var/lib/kafka/data] Loading producer state till offset 69396839 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.UnifiedLog$)
[2024-01-31 08:32:45,310] INFO [LogLoader partition=some-topic-0, dir=/var/lib/kafka/data] Reloading from producer snapshot and rebuilding producer state from offset 69396839 (kafka.log.UnifiedLog$)
[2024-01-31 08:32:45,310] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=some-topic-0] Loading producer state from snapshot file 'SnapshotFile(/var/lib/kafka/data/some-topic-0/00000000000069396839.snapshot,69396839)' (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2024-01-31 08:32:53,443] INFO Error while loading logs in /var/lib/kafka/data/some-topic-0 in 8136ms (68/154 completed in /var/lib/kafka/data) (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2024-01-31 08:32:53,444] ERROR There was an error in one of the threads during logs loading: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

In those tests, the .snapshot file size was between 100 and 500 MB, which should not pose a problem if it was loaded fully into memory. However, it seems like there are several threads doing the same for other segments/snapshots, because there are further "Recovering unflushed segment" messages after the error message. So maybe the issue is that several snapshot files are loaded at once and overwhelm the memory?

There is a setting `num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir` (number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown), but it is set to 1. We only have one data directory (/var/lib/kafka/data). Maybe there are several jobs in a queue that are still started after such an error and the problem is that files loaded earlier are not collected by GC in time?